# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, iframe, textarea

I want to dynamically created "iframe's textarea" Inserting the value of the variable. But, it's error.

What should I do?

**P.S:** browser is chrome

```
    for(k=0;;){<br>
       key_id2[k] = storage.getItem("key_id["+k+"]");
       val_contain2[k] = storage.getItem("val_contain["+k+"]");
       document.getElementById(key_id2[k] ).contentWindow.document.getElementById( "textmode" ).value = val_contain2[k];
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: The element can not be found that is your problem. My guess, you are trying to set the value before that page is loaded.

Comment: your id "key_id2[k]" not found. Please show us more than this!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can achieve this

```
<script>
    function doneLoading() {
        var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "NOFIDDLE";
    }
</script>
<iframe onload="doneLoading();" width=400 height=300 src="//fiddle.jshell.net"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3EV5/

Your javascript is probably executed before the onload.